# How can I unlock the lost phone's lost mode remotely?

Tags: xiaomi, lost-phone, redmi

I lost my phone Redmi Note 10, 2 days ago, and consulted the police for IMEI tracing.
Today I accidentally locked my lost phone by putting it in lost mode. And there is no option for unlocking the lost mode remotely.
Actually, I do not want to lock it or put it in lost mode because the police are tracking the phone. so, How can I unlock the lost mode remotely?